# Images are loading slowly in viewpager with async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

In my app we have an viewpager which is used to display user gallery images , If user want to upload a new image i got same image path but with different image ,

If I use picasso or any third party libraries It's not getting update so I use async task to upload an image, its working fine but Images are loading very slowly 
                   how to load images with out any third party libraries....?

Comment: What has a viewpager to do with uploading new images? To where?

Comment: when i swipe  images in view pager its loading very slowly when i use async task , if i use third party libraries all images have same path so when i replace an image its not updating...

Comment: You have not answered my question. You did not even use the word upload.

Comment: viewpager is not updating when we upload a new image

Comment: You fail to explain a connection between a viewpager for gallery images and uploading images. Uploading to where? To which server?